# How does the James Webb Space Telescope avoid stick/slip and creep problems when positioning its mirrors?

Tags: friction, astronomy, satellites, telescopes, space-travel

The JWST is now positioning its mirrors so they form a single image. [How James Webb's Mirrors MUST Work](https://youtu.be/-cUp0AEwV2w) To do this, each mirror must be positioned in 8 nanometer steps in 6 degrees of freedom. Here is a fascinating video on the actuators that do the positioning: [The Clever Engineering of NASA's Cryogenic Nano-Actuators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MxH1sfJLBQ)

Accurately positioning a moving object is not a trivial task. For example, a [ruling engine](http://183.181.162.36/about/feelnikon/recollections/r12_e/index.htm) is one of the most difficult machines to make. A ruling engine scribes the grooves on a diffraction grating with extremely precise parallelism and spacing.

The job of the JWST actuators is simpler than this. But it shares some of the same difficulties. For example, the actuator contains a ball screw that must slide in submicrometer steps for the actuator to move on its coarse scale. In particular, I was wondering about stick/slip motion and creep. These course notes on [Friction](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/112/102/112102015/) discuss stick/slip.

[A Piezo-Stepping Diffraction Grating Ruling Engine with Continuous Grating-Blank Position Control](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.7567/JJAPS.14S1.169) discusses stick/slip and creep in connection with ruling engines.

Static friction is caused by two surfaces contacting each other at a few high points. The pressure is so high that the softer material deforms. The surface area in contact increases and the pressure drops until deformation stops. The surfaces weld together at these high points.

To move the objects, a mechanism must push sideways. On a scale of nanometer movement, everything is a spring. The mechanism compresses before pushing hard enough to break the welds. Once the surfaces are moving, the coefficient of dynamic friction is generally lower than static friction. So when the surfaces begin to slip, they jerk. If you are moving in nanometer steps, it is easy to overshoot.

Dynamic friction still isn't $0$. The mechanism is still loaded when the surfaces reach their destination. The surfaces weld when they stop. But the residual force from the mechanism can cause them to slowly creep as stresses relax.

The problems of stick/slip get worse when large forces press the surfaces together. In ruling engines, the carriages that carry large diffraction gratings can be hundreds of kg. Sometimes they are floated in Hg to reduce the load. Obviously this is not a problem in orbit. But vacuum welding might well more than make up for it.

I understand that great progress has been made on vacuum welding. But the JWST complex deployment was the biggest risk to the mission. It required a lot of moving parts, and one of them might have failed. Stick/slip is at a level far below parts freezing together. Yet nobody mentioned any danger of not being able to align the mirrors. Smooth sailing is expected.

It seems that creep would be a problem for the fine scale. The actuator fine scale adjusts mirror position in 8 nanometer steps through gear reductions and a clever flexure. A flexure adjusts its position by bending. This doesn't sound like the most stable mechanism.  But if you wait, stresses will relax and it will stop moving.

The problem is that the JWST has moving parts, and moving parts cause vibration. Some instruments need to be cooled below what can be achieved through radiation. So a small cryocooler was added. It has some insane engineering to reduce vibration, but it isn't $0$. See [The Insane Engineering of James Webb Telescope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aICaAEXDJQQ).

Also the orientation of the JWST is adjusted many times per second with reaction wheels. The idea is to keep the telescope still, so each nudge is tiny. But nanometers...

So how are these problems solved?